# Pulling duration stats API in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

In airflow, the "Gantt" chart offers quite a good view on performance of the ran tasks. It offers stats like start/end time, duration and etc.

Do you guys know a way to programmatically pull these stats via the Airflow API? I would like to use these stats and generate periodic reports on the performance of my tasks and how it changes over time.

My airflow version is: 1.9
Python: 3.6.3
Running on top of docker

Thanks!
Kelvin

Airflow online documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy approach could be to set up a SQL alchemy connection, airflow stores/sends all the data in there once the configuration is completed(dag info/stat/fail, task info/stats/ etc.).

Edit *airflow.cfg* and add:

`sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://------/table_name`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/metrics.html), Airflow can send metrics in StatsD format including

> `dag.<dag_id>.<task_id>.duration` - Seconds taken to finish a task

Unfortunately I don't see there anything like start/end time metric.